# Nodes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning JavaScript and I've got a question for you guys. The thing is that I'm trying to wrap my head around some event handlers, but while doing so I've come to realize that there is something that I don't understand about nodes.

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/ljnissen/ett4vs73/) that works fine when I use jQuery:

```
var canvas = $('#cvs');

canvas.mousemove(function(e){
     var pageCrds = '('+ e.pageX +', ' + e.pageY +')';

     var b = document.getElementById("first");
     b.firstChild.nodeValue = "(e.pageX, e.pageY) - "+ pageCrds;   
});
```

but [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/ljnissen/ha6rcwjs/) is not working:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('cvs');

canvas.mousemove(function(e){
    var pageCrds = '('+ e.pageX +', ' + e.pageY +')';

    var b = document.getElementById("first");
    b.firstChild.nodeValue = "(e.pageX, e.pageY) - "+ pageCrds;   
});
```

The HTML that I am using is the same in both cases:

```
 <canvas id="cvs" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div id="first">Move mouse over canvas.</div>
       <p id="one"></p>    
       <p id="two"></p>
```

Can anybody shed some light as to why the jQuery-version works and not the one in pure JavaScript? Obviously, I would like to be able to do my task in pure JavaScript as well as in jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not using jQuery, you'll need to use `onmousemove`

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
    var pageCrds = '('+ e.pageX +', ' + e.pageY +')';

    var b = document.getElementById("first");
    b.firstChild.nodeValue = "(e.pageX, e.pageY) - "+ pageCrds;   
};
```

Comment: or better `addEventListener()`.

Comment: Yeah `addEventListener()` would be the recommended way. I just posted a minimal-change fix.

Comment: jQuery selectors return facades on the actual document objects, so document.getElementById and $(...) are not the same thing

Answer (score 1):

the function `canvas.mousemove()` is jquery, you have to use non-jquery equivalent `canvas.onmousemove = function(e){}` or `canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){}, useCapture);`.  The `useCapture` value replaces the return value from the handler and determines whether the event continues to 'bubble'.